# How to delete every second files in Windows 10 folder?

Tags: explorer, frames

I have an animation image sequence that contains around 100000 image files. However, I find out that the animation is happening too slowly and taking quite much space, so I figured out that it would be good idea to remove half of the frames to speed up the animation. However, I have no idea how do I delete that many files without messing up the image sequence. The images are named numeric order 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg...etc.

I found out that in smaller scale operation you would just scale your explorer window down to 2 rows and then select and delete the other row, but this time it's just too much scrolling to be useful method. I need some sort of a program that can do it for me. I am not a programmer, but artist, so I think I need something quite easy to follow method or some explorer application that has this kind of tools.

Comment: Do you want to do it with some scripting languages?

Answer (score 3):

ben101's answer is a good choice, but if you really want a program, here's a very simple Powershell script:

```
rm *0.*
rm *2.*
rm *4.*
rm *6.*
rm *8.*
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check if I can figure out how to use that powershell.

Answer (score 1):

Look up

```
*0.jpg OR *2.jpg OR *4.jpg OR *6.jpg OR *8.jpg
```

in the search box of windows explorer. It should then give you all the even pictures then just hit CTRL + A to select them all and delete.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this and the other method provided if some of them works best for me.

Answer (score 1):

it is also of note that if you batch-renamed a file using (select-files, rename) - in an Explorer window - then windows will append something like (#) to the end (# being the number of a file's place in the series of files being renamed)[ex: yo (1).png, yo (2).png , and so on].

The added parenthesis will mess with the search in the explorer. So you have to then use double quotes `" "` around the solution that user13880320 proposed. e.g.

```
"*1).jpg" "*3).jpg"  "*5).jpg" "*7).jpg" "*9).jpg"
```

and so on.

Doing it this way will make the explorer search recognise the parenthesis as a character in a string rather than something else that it will omit from the search term.